# How to use regex in java to match a word

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a word (Source Ip) where each letter can be small or capital letter so i have wrote a regex pattern down but  my `m.find()` is showing false even for Correct Match...

Is there any wrong in my regex pattern or the way I have written is wrong?

```
  String word = "Source Ip";
    String pattern = "[S|s][O|o][U|u][R|r][C|c][E|e]\\s*[I|i][P|p]";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(word);
    System.out.println(m.find());
```

Comment: Since you have \\s* in your pattern, it would match any number of whitespace characters (even none) between both words, so `SourceIp` and `Source        Ip` would match.

Comment: I wonder why everyone is rushing to answer, while the  original code [returns *true*](https://ideone.com/lV9eZK). Surely the regex is not correct since `|` is matching a literal `|`, but I think the problem is that word boundary should be used: `(?i)\\bsource\\s*ip\\b`.

Comment: @stribizhev you have a point, but "is there any wrog in my regex pattern or the way i have written is wrong" (cit.) could use an answer I guess.

Comment: CASE_INSENSITIVE is best. but if you want in specific means i can suggest this ^S?OURCE IP|source ip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to alternate all letters between upper case and lowercase (note, as mentioned by others, the character class idiom does not require `|` to alternate - adding it between square brackets will also match the `|` literal).

You can parametrize your `Pattern` initialization with the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag (alternative inline usage would be `(?i)` before your pattern representation).

For instance:

```
Pattern.compile("(?i)source\\s*ip");
```

... or ...

```
Pattern.compile("source\\s*ip", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

**Note**

Flag API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE).

Comment: I would suggest this as an accepted answer cause it mentions the both possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

You can simple use

```
String pattern = "SOURCE\\s*IP";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` will make the matching case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has the problem of accepting **sourceip** as well.

```
source\s*ip
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/sbSb6kOddJIyy2z3)

Therefore the **correct answer** should be

```
source\s+ip
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/UDWSHv7sggO6oaP1)

to force the presence of at least one whitespace between the two words.

To use this expression in Java you have to escape the backslash and use something like:

```
Pattern.compile("source\\s+ip", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Answer (score -2):

if you really want to use regex though for some reason and not pattern. methods then this regex should suit your needs and it works just fine in java for me

```
 [s|S][o|O][U|u][r|R][c|C][e|E][ ]*[i|I][p|P]
```

your case of using

```
\\s*
```

won't identify spaces however this will

```
 \s*
```

you had one slash too many  :)

EDIT:
I demonstrate my ignorance, after checking regexpal I was wrong, [sS] is better than [s|S]
[sS][oO][Uu][rR][cC][eE][ ]*[iI][pP]
thank you Pshemo
and yes i completely forgot about escaping characters Mena thank you for pointing that out for me

Comment: You actually need to double-escape predefined character classes. `\s` won't compile. `\\s` is required.

Comment: `[s|S]` matches `s` or `|` or `S`. I doubt that you want to include `|` here.

Comment: cheers guys, you are right and i said so in my edit. Thank you for the corrections, its good to learn from mistakes.